# Hot get List of objects with Hibernate, when Entity mapped as Many To One

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class `User`, that contains List of `Contacts`
User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String login;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Contact> contacts;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Contact class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Contact implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_profile_id")
        private User owner;
        ...
        ...
    }
```

how may i get List of Contacts by User.id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I got what you want...

Simply look for the User by Id, and you will get his/her contacts. However, the collection will be lazy loaded, and the list will be really loaded when you will call `getContacts()` or `Hibernate.initialize(user.getContacts())`. Change FetchMode as EAGER in the @OneToMany in case you don't want lazy loading...

For e.g., using HQL Query :

```
String hql = "from User where id = :userid";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setInteger("userid", myUserIdIWantContacts);
User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
```

or Criteria :

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id", myUserIdIWantContacts));
User user = (User) cr.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: so, i just have to call User.getContacts() and all other job will be done automaticly because i set @OneToMany to this field?

Comment: Yeah ! Hibernate will automatically retrieve all contacts associated to your user :) That's how Hibernate works ! With your annotation, Hibernate will lazy load your collection of Contact. Use fetch = FetchMode.EAGER in your @OneToMany in case you want the list of contact directly

Answer (score 0):

`Contact` has a foreign key column associated to `User` so you don't need to use join

```
from Contact where owner.id = :userId
```

Please, don't use primitive types like `int id`, use `Integer id` instead.

Comment: this answer is also correct, but i used second one.